# Python 3 XOR bytearrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-xor

Is there a built in function in python 3 that can `bitwise-xor` bytes? For example, if I have 2 bytearrays:

```
one = oE1ltQSsoEqRC4j1EMz1ORU1dyucIcI4WstKz-uhuKA=
two = Rffs1PW5zA1h5RFVh5MkLw5R7a2QVHY7cwnjuSPktwc=

one XOR two = 5bqJYfEVbEfw7pmgl1_RFhtkmoYMdbQDKcKpdshFD6c=
```

Comment: Those look like base64 encoded strings (but aren't, since they're invalidly padded).

Comment: @AKX I believe they're 32byte strings

Comment: While actually each one has 44 bytes.

Comment: "please bear with me if this is common knowledge." No, that would be the opposite of doing your own research before asking.

Comment: @user1045890 Even if I add another padding `=` to the first string, I only get 31 bytes.

Comment: Those are not strings or bytes, they're syntax errors. Please show valid initializations so it's clear what you actually have to work with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, if you have two `bytes`es, you can do

```
one_xor_two = bytes(a ^ b for (a, b) in zip(one, two))
```

to element-wise XOR them.

In your case, you'd first base64 decode the strings, then XOR, then base64 encode... however, the example strings won't work due to Python not liking the bad padding in them.

```
import base64

one = base64.b64decode('oE1ltQSsoEqRC4j1EMz1ORU1dyucIcI4WstKz-uhuKA=')
two = base64.b64decode('Rffs1PW5zA1h5RFVh5MkLw5R7a2QVHY7cwnjuSPktwc=')

one_xor_two = bytes(a ^ b for (a, b) in zip(one, two))

print(base64.b64encode(one_xor_two))
```

Comment: Except that neither string is base64.

Comment: As noted in the answer, yes.

Comment: And even if they were base64 (by artificially adding missing padding) then the result doesn't match what OP states. The question is invalid IMO.

Comment: The question asks how to element-wise XOR two bytearrays together. I do agree that the example data is suspect as it's not anywhere near correct, but at least the question as it was asked is answered.