# Python xoring bytearray with append mehtod

Tags: python, cryptography

Hi I am trying to break single-byte xor cipher.
So currently I am given hex-string text file.
What I have done so far is following :

1. I opened text file and stored it into variable.

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    file = f.read()
```

2. I converted `file` into bytearray using :

```
barr = bytearray.fromhex(file)
```

3. Now I am trying xor `barr` with all possible character(0~ 255). This is the part that I am not sure if I am doing wrong.

```
def fixedxor(barr, xor_to):
    blen = len(barr)
    new_barr = bytearray(b'')
    for i in range(blen):
       new_barr.append(barr[i] ^ xor_to)
    
    return new_barr
```

Is there any problem to xor two things with above function?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean if it's ok to `xor` two things? You need at least two inputs to do an xor function. You can take a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52851092/11286032) for more information on xoring byte arrays

Comment: @MarceloPaco I meant if it’s okay to xor two parameters given above function. I have to xor two object that has same length but since the second parameter is single character repeating itself as much as the length of first parameter, I was thinking if I can define empty byte array and append each xored column to the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe the following code snippet answers your question

```py
import itertools

filecontents = "18041f1f184f050b020d17"
filebytes = bytearray.fromhex(filecontents)
key = itertools.cycle(b"password")

decoded = bytearray([a^b for a,b in zip(filebytes, key)])
print(decoded)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes! It answers my question but would you be able to point out the wrong part from my approach. I spent too much time figuring out why it doesn’t work, I want to move on but wanna understand it at least.

Comment: change to `i%blen` probably...